# Why does xstep get returned as a negative value

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

I have the following snippet of code extending GLWallpaperService in an app:

```
    @Override
    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
            float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
    super.onOffsetsChanged(xOffset,yOffset,xStep,yStep,xPixels,yPixels);
    VideoLiveWallpaper.xStep = xStep;
    VideoLiveWallpaper.yStep = yStep;
    Log.w("General", "xStep: " + xStep);
    Log.w("General", "yStep: " + yStep);
```

When I run this my understanding is that xstep should return a value between 0 and 1, essentially allowing me to determine the number of screens by dividing the xstep value by 1.  However, every time I run this on my Sony Xperia Ion the xstep is returned as -1.  I have five homescreens setup so this is not just a default for a single homescreen.

I have tried searching Google but did not see anyone else who seems to be having the same problem.  Is this a bug in my particular phone?  Is there a better way to determine the number of homescreens and how much a wallpaper should scroll as they move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find the reason why this occurs, but I did find another piece of code that addresses the issue.  Here is the relevant portion, in case it helps anyone else:

```
 if (xStep <= 0.0f && VideoLiveWallpaper.xStep == 0) {
      xStep = xOffset / 2; // originator didn't set step size, assume we're halfway
```

It seems to work as long as the home screen (middle screen) is up when the wallpaper starts.  That's not perfect, but it works better than my method of assuming 5 screens (xStep = 0.25) in all cases when it's zero...